# Decreasing order of powers ignoring specific string in sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, sympy, polynomials

I am making quiz of mathematics for my students.

How do we align polynomial about x in decreasing order of powers ignoring specific string in sympy?

I want to treat symbol 'a' as constant and want to order decreasing order of powers about symbol 'x', in other words, I want to ignore 'a' to order it.  I have no idea to realize it.

My minimum code as follows:

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import x

sympy.init_printing(order='lex')

a = sympy.Symbol('a')
f = sympy.Function('f')
g = sympy.Function('g')
h = sympy.Function('h')

f = 4*x + 1
g = x**2 + a*x + a**2
h = 4*x + a

sympy.latex(f)
sympy.latex(g)
sympy.latex(h)
```

Sympy returns as follows when I run above code:

```
4 x + 1
a^2 + a x + x^2
a + 4 x.
```

However, I expect following result;

```
4 x + 1
x^2 + a x + a^2
4 x + a.
```

Sympy seems to recognize both of 'a' and 'x' as symbols and seems to align alphabetically.

How do I have to fix my code to get my expected result?

Comment: You could tell sympy that you are working with polynomials in `x`: `sympy.latex(sympy.poly(h, x))`.  Also note that `f = sympy.Function('f')` has no effect as the assignment gets thrown away when you call `f = 4*x + 1`.